# How to pass string which is searched and pagenumber together for ajax call to achieve pagination

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

here my aim is to paginate the searched records of book_search.php.Totally there are 16 records when i give "S" and i used limit in sql query to display only 4 records in each page.But when i executee for the first time It Will give first 4 records with next and previous link correctly, but for the remaining records when i click next it dosen't display anything. here there are 3 files i have used 
1)book_search.php 2)ajax.php 3)script.js
Here i have used ajax call for executing the records and how to pass string which is to searched and page number to ajax call when jquery button is clicked in order to work the pagination in remaning records, can u please help in getting the solutuions please.Thank you in advance.
book_search.php

```
<?php
include('assets/page_header.php');
?>


<div class="container">

<h1>SEARCHING THE BOOK</h1>

<form  id="search"  name="search" action="#" method="post">
Search : <input type="text" name="author" id="author">
<input id="submit" name="submit"  type="submit" value="Submit">

</form><div id="display">


</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$page="";
if(isset($_GET['page']))
{
$page=$_GET['page'];
echo $page;
}
$num_rec_per_page = 5;
?>
<div id="navigation">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php if(isset($page)) echo $page;?>">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['author']))
{

    $author=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
    if($author=="")
    {
        echo "Please Enter Title or Author or Publisher";
    }
    else
    {


        if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
        $start_from = ($page-1) * $num_rec_per_page; 

        $query1="select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'  LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page  ";
        echo $query1;
        $rs_result=mysql_query("select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'"); 


        $total_records = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);  
        echo $total_records;//count number of records
        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $num_rec_per_page); 
        $phpself=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if($page>1)
        {
        $pagenumber=$page-1;
        $prev="<a href=\"$phpself?page=$pagenumber\">[Back]</a>";
        $first="<a href=\"$phpself?page=1\">[FirstPage]</a>";
        }
        else
        {
        $prev='';
        $first='';
        }
        if($page<$total_pages)
        {
        $pagenumber=$page+1;
        $next="<a href=\"$phpself?page=$pagenumber\">[Next]</a>";
        $last="<a href=\"$phpself?page=$total_pages\">[LastPage]</a>";
        }
        else
        {

        $next="";
        $last="";
        /*$next='[next]';
        $last='[LastPage]';*/
        }
        //for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
           // echo "<a href='members1.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i."</a> "; 

      //  };


        echo $first.$prev."Showing page<bold>$page</bold>of<bold>$total_pages</bold>pages".$next.$last;

        /*if($total_records > 0) {
            echo "<a href='members1.php?page=1'> ".'<'." </a> "; // Goto 1st page  
        }
         // echo "<a href='members1.php?page=1'> ".'<<'." </a> ";



        if($total_records > 0) {
            echo "<a href='members1.php?page=$total_pages'> ".'>'." </a> "; // Goto last page
        }*/


        $result1=mysql_query($query1) or  die(mysql_error());
        //print_r($result1);
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
        //echo $count;
        $display= "<table align='center'>";
        $display.= "<tr><td>title</td>   <td>author</td>   <td>publisher</td>   <td>numcopies</td>    <td>status</td>    <td>number_of_copies_available</td> <td>Action</td> </tr>";
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
            $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
            //print_r($row['bookid']);
            $r12=$row['bookid'];
            $query2=mysql_query("select bookid from bookrentalinfo where bookid=$r12");
            $num_copies_borrowed=mysql_num_rows($query2);   
            $num_copies_count=$row['numcopies'];
            $number_of_copies_available=$num_copies_count-$num_copies_borrowed;
            $display.= "<tr>";
            //echo "<td>".$row['bookid']."</td>";
        $display.="<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['author']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['publisher']."</td>";
            $display.= "<td>".$row['numcopies']."</td>";        
            $display.= "<td>".$row['status']."</td>";   
            $display.= "<td>".$number_of_copies_available."</td>";
            if($number_of_copies_available>0)
            {
                $display.= "<td><a href='borrow_search.php?book_id=".$row['bookid']."'>Rent</a></td>";      
            }
            else {
                $display.= "rent link is not activated";
                $display.="<td></td>";      
            }

            $display.= "</tr>";
        }
        $display.="</table>";
        echo $display;

    }
}
?>

    </div>

    </html>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#renewaldate" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0});
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
    //console.log("div value"+$('#display').html());
    var author = $("#author").val();



    var dataString='author='+author;


        if(author=='')
        {
        alert("Please Enter Author or Title or Publisher Fields");
        }
        else
        {
            // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "db/ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
            //alert("submitted"+result);
            $('#display').html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert(thrownError);
            }
            });
        }
        e.preventDefault(); 
        });
});
```

Comment: First you could check what Queries are executed, for every request, and check this queries directly in MySQL, to se if the error is in the php part or in the SQL Queries.

Comment: I Have Checked the sql queries by executing in sql yog , it is working fine error might be in part

Comment: i mean error might be in php part

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in your JavaScript part, you do not pass you pagenumber.
Try editing your script.js to:

**EDIT 2** Added '&' in data String

```
var author = $("#author").val();
var page   = $("#page").val();

var dataString='author='+author+'&page='+page;
```

and add a inputfield with the pagenumber and ID "page", to the outputs of you ajax.php.

And move the ending `</form>`-Tag behind your "display"-Div.

**EDIT** you should start with Page 0, at the beginning. Add this to you Ajax.php

**EDIT 3** changed to page 1

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo isset($page)?$page:1;;?>">
```

By the way ... yout ajax.php is writing a `</html>` you should remove this, because you already have a closing html-tag in you page.

Comment: Ok sir i willl try this

Comment: Sir, I added this but now it dosen't display the table result when i give "s" and next and previous links are disabled .

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page">

Comment: I added but in ajax call  datastring is not passing, so i dosen't get any result now

Comment: Whats you Querystring you receive in you ajax.php ?

Comment: In my querystring i get author=s page=

Comment: Check the value of your 'page' inputfield at the first page.

Comment: I am getting null value for the page

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="page" id="page">  here whether we need to include value field?

Comment: Do you have the correct number in you html-code of your "page" input-field ?

See my "EDIT 3" of my post, this should help

Comment: No sir still i get nothing in page variable

Comment: in your code you have a value-tag for you input, so you should find out, why this value tag is not displayed.

Comment: Now i get 1 as page number in datastring but result of the record dosen't display

Comment: Than you should have `LIMIT 0, 5` in your SQL Query now. Can you confirm this ?

Comment: $query1="select * from books  where  title LIKE '%$author%' OR author LIKE '%$author%' OR publisher LIKE '%$author%'  LIMIT $start_from, $num_rec_per_page  ";

Comment: you should echo this $quey1 to see if all variables are inserted correctly.

Comment: select * from books where title LIKE '%s%' OR author LIKE '%s%' OR publisher LIKE '%s%' LIMIT 0, 5 I get Correct

Comment: Sounds good. do you see any outputs of your content in html-code ?